# Как в настройках, intellij idea, изменить символ, используемый для десятичного числа с запятой на точку?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Как в настройках, intellij idea, изменить символ, используемый для десятичного числа с запятой на точку? Дело в том, что double использует 4.1 (точку ), но при чтении из строки или файла требует запятую. [Код из учебника, дело не в нем,нужны настройки intellij idea](http://%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%20%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0,%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0,%20%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%83%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20intelij%20idea)

```
String str1 = "2 3.4 5 6 7.4 9.1 10.5 qqq";
Scanner src = new Scanner(str1);
while (src.hasNext()) {
    if (src.hasNextDouble()) {
        sum += src.nextDouble();
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Как именно требует?  Говорит "требую запятую"?

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста как оно это требует. Лог ошибки например.

Answer (score 2):

```
String str1 = "2 3.4 5 6 7.4 9.1 10.5 qqq";
Scanner src = new Scanner(str1);        

while (src.hasNextDouble()) {
    sum += src.nextDouble();
    count++;
}
```

Запятая там не используется, а код у вас зацикливается когда доходит до "qqq"

Comment: Это не весь код, а qqq это строка для выхода(учебный код)

Answer (score 2):

Глупый сканер использует установки локализации.
Можно попробовать переключиться на Locale с нужным разделителем дробной части.
Если что, можно даже переключаться туда-обратно.

```
String str1 = "2 3.4 5 6 7.4 9.1 10.5 qqq";
Scanner src = new Scanner(str1);
while (src.hasNext()) {
    src.useLocale(Locale.US);
    if (src.hasNextDouble()) {
        sum += src.nextDouble();
        count++;
    }
    src.useLocale(Locale.getDefault()); // или src.reset();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, учту на будущее, но этот код из учебника и мне нудно настроить Intellij idea

Comment: Хотя, использование src.useLocale(Locale.US); решает проблему!

Comment: Это зависит от настройки локализации операционной системы. Зайдите в панель управления, языки и стандарты, там настраивайте. Каким образом Inteliji может менять эти настройки даже не представляю:)

Comment: Это я сделал в первую очередь), Но видимо в настройках idea есть какие то региональные опции.