# Десятичный разделитель в IntellJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где в настройках IntellJ IDEA выставляется десятичный разделитель?

У меня это по умолчанию "," Т. е. если я использую методы класса Scanner, то при вводе вещественных чисел обязан отделять дробную часть от целой **запятой**. Иначе - ошибка.
В то время как вывод результатов вычислений прописывается с **точкой**.

Я пробовал менять разделитель в настройках Windows, с последующим перезапуском IntellJ IDEA, но на вход всё так же требовали **запятую**, а на выходе была **точка** в вещественных числах.
Могу предположить, что на этапе установки IDEA этот пункт однажды фиксируется (в соответствии с текущими настройками локализации WIndows), и всё. Но это уж слишком радикально для такого серьёзного софта. :)

Загуглить, как ни пытался, не смог. :( Так что, уважаемые, выручайте!

Даю [link](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1130944/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85-intellij-idea-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%87) на похожий вопрос, но там нет КОНКРЕТНОГО ответа, однако может вас натолкнёт на мысль.

Comment: Как раз в комментариях к ответу по вашей ссылке предложили использовать `scanner.useLocale(Locale.US)` Вот вам и ввод с дробных чисел точкой

Comment: Что ж, тогда раскройте, пожалуйста, скобки. Что значит использовать `scanner.useLocale(Locale.US)`? Это прописывается в настройках где-то? Или же мне в коде нужно создавать объекты класса Scanner c видоизменённым названием этого самого класса? Потому что мне этот сухой ответ к тому вопросу ничего не даёт.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

По умолчанию сканнер использует системную локаль. Так как у вас система на русском языке - используется `ru_RU`. В ней дробный разряд числа отделяется запятой, значит нужно сменить локаль.

Для этого есть несколько спсобов:

- Изменение локали сканнера:

Вы можете установить определенному объекту `scanner` нужную локаль (даже отличную от локали остальной программы)

Пример:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
scanner.useLocale(Locale.US);
```

---

- Изменение локали всей программы:

Вы можете задать использование нужной локали с нужного места в программе. Для этого используется `Locale.setDefault(Locale locale)`. Обратите внимание, что изменения локали отражается только на объектах, созданных **после вызова** `Locale.setDefault()`.

То есть в этом коде:

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
```

сканнер будет использовать локаль `en_US`, а в этом:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
Scanner newScanner = new Scanner("Some text");
```

объект `scanner` все еще использует `ru_RU`, а `newScanner` уже `en_US`

---

- Установка локали всей программы с помощью флагов JVM:

Для установки локали `en_US` вы можете использовать флаги:

```
-Duser.language=en -Duser.region=US
```

Что бы их установить в IntellJ IDEA:

- *Run -> Edit Configurations -> VM options* -> устанавливаете там эти флаги.

Либо,

- Выберите текущую конфигурацию (рядом с кнопкой *Build*) -> *Edit Configurations -> ... также, как и в примере выше*

---

Но учтите, что теперь вы **обязаны** отделять дробные разряды точкой (либо менять локаль обратно)

Comment: Станислав, вы отлично всё расписали! Равзе что забыли добавить, что для вызова метода `*.useLocale(Locale.US);` необходимо импортировать: `import java.util.Locale;`. А так - огромное Вам спасибо! :)