# Ошибка при считывании типа double сканером

Tags: java

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
    
public class TaxiCost {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final double FARE_PER_KM = 8; 
        
        double startIndicationOdo, endIndicationOdo, way, tax; 
        
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Введите начальные показания одометра: ");
        startIndicationOdo = input.nextDouble();
        
        System.out.print("Введите конечные показания одометра: ");
        endIndicationOdo = input.nextDouble();
        
        way = (int )((endIndicationOdo - startIndicationOdo) * 100 + 0.5) / 100.0;
        
        tax = (int )((way * FARE_PER_KM) * 100 + 0.5) / 100.0;
        
        System.out.println("Вы проехали " + way + ". Из расчета 8 руб. за км,");
        System.out.println("стоимость проезда равна " + tax + " руб.");
    }
}
```

Компиляцию успешно проходит. Но когда в консоли cmd(win10) ввести число типа double, выдает ошибку:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
```

А если ввести целое число, ошибку не выдает.

Почему так происходит?

Comment: используй точку вместо запятой. Или наоборот.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос данные, что вводите

Comment: Еще одна странность. Если в консоли вводить число через запятую (напр 150,6), то ошибку не выдает. Может дело в "-encoding utf-8" на этапе компиляции?

Comment: На вашем компьютере установлена русская локаль (язык). В настройках сказано что десятичный разделитель запятая (`,`). Вам следует использовать запятую при вводе данных. Если вы хотите вводить числа с десятичной точкой (`.`), то надо сменить локаль. NB: локаль не влияет на разделитель в коде программы, только на данные при вводе и выводе.

Comment: Можно сменить локаль у сканнера: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1240732/416121

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в том, что при создании `Scanner` используется локаль по умолчанию `Locale.getDefault()`, и метод `input.nextDouble()` использует эти региональные настройки (для русской локали, как и для многих других европейских: немецкой, французской, итальянской и др., используется десятичная запятая вместо десятичной точки).

Существует несколько способов изменения локали:

- задать системные свойства при запуске: `java -Duser.language=ru -Duser.region=RU`
- аналогично вызвать `Locale.setDefault(new Locale("ru", "RU"));` перед созданием сканера
- после создания сканера можно использовать метод [`input.useLocale();`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#useLocale(java.util.Locale)) (текущую локаль сканера возвращает метод [`Scanner::locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#locale()))

Альтернативный вариант -- всегда использовать один и тот же разделитель.  К примеру, метод `Double.parseDouble` [всегда использует десятичную точку](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40551129/13279831) независимо от локали:

```java
String myDouble = input.nextLine(); 
double d = Double.parseDouble(myDouble);
```

Тогда может понадобиться костыль в виде принудительной замены десятичной запятой на десятичную точку (например, используя `String::replace/replaceAll`).