# Что делать если ввод числа double читает число с запятой, а надо с точкой в Java

Tags: java, scanner, double

Ввожу переменную в Java типа double с точкой, но выводит ошибку, что надо вводить не с точкой, а с запятой. Как это можно исправить.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ошибка при считывании типа double сканером](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1335539/)

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120/385375)

Comment: "но выводит ошибку, что надо вводить не с точкой, а с запятой" - вводить с запятой :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В русской локализации дробные числа по умолчанию разделяются запятыми, а не точками. Поэтому вылетает исключение. Можно пытаться сменить локализацию у *Scanner*, но есть вариант попроще: считывать *String*, и затем конвертировать в *double* с помощью *Double.parseDouble()*. Этот метод всегда использует для разделителей точки вне зависимости от локализации.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyProject {
    private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = scanner.next();
        double result = Double.parseDouble(str);

        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Если вы хотите, чтобы срабатывало и с точками, и с запятыми, можно предварительно заменять все запятые в строке на точки.
Тогда получится следующий код:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyProject {
    private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = scanner.next();
        double result = convertToDouble(str);

        System.out.println(result);
    }

    private static double convertToDouble(String str) {
        str = str.replace(',', '.');
        return Double.parseDouble(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: А где же ссылка на чудо-сайт beauty of Java?

Comment: _Если вы хотите, чтобы срабатывало и с точками, и с запятыми, можно предварительно заменять все запятые в строке на точки._  Запятые _могут_ использоваться как разделитель тысяч в английской/американской локали, которая может стоять _по умолчанию_

Comment: В моём сердце))